# Laravel parent-child data displaying in Bootstrap table in blade

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a simple Laravel project to show parent records in a table, with collapsible row(s) to show child records. I have a nice Bootstrap table, can join the parent and child tables in my controller and populate the table, but can't group the children under the one parent. I'm not sure if I built the passed dataset incorrectly in my controller, or if I'm missing some "Laravel way" to do this. It's an easy proposition, loop through the parents until one has a child, then loop through it's children, then resume looping parents, etc., but it's driving me insane. I can't find any direct example or reference to solve my issue, but this is a common requirement.

I need to know how to reference the child records to loop through them to populate the collapsed section. My attempts either result in a parent row for each individual child (the code shown) or a bunch of duplicated child items. If I could pass two datasets from my controller, one of parents and a separate of children, then I could in code build this, but I don't know how to do that in Laravel or if there's an easier way.

I did start with Laravel DataTables but to get detail child rows requires implementing handlebar templates in Laravel and I couldn't find a usable reference to do that, so decided to revert to from-scratch-code my own using a Bootstrap table. Than I got stuck.

Here's my controller (DataassetsController.php). The "investment-accounts" table contains parents (as do the other joined tables), and the "investment-line-items" table contains child records for the "investment-accounts".

```
class DataassetsController extends Controller
{

     public function getUnion()
     {

        $money = DB::table('monetary_assets')
        ->select(['monetary_asset_name as name', 'monetary_asset_type as type', 'monetary_asset_value as value', DB::raw("NULL as item"), DB::raw("NULL as institution_id"), DB::raw("NULL as item_id")]);

        $personal = DB::table('personal_property_assets')
        ->select(['personal_name as name', 'personal_type as type', 'personal_current_value as value', DB::raw("NULL as item"), DB::raw("NULL as institution_id"), DB::raw("NULL as item_id")]);


        $investments = DB::table('investment_accounts')
        ->join('investment_line_items', 'investment_institution_name_id', '=', 'investment_accounts.id')
        ->select(['investment_institution_name as name', 'Investment_account_type as type', DB::raw("NULL as value"), 'investment_name as item', 'investment_institution_name_id as institution_id', 'investment_accounts.id as item_id' ]);


        $union = DB::table('real_property_assets')
        ->select(['real_name as name', 'real_type as type', 'real_current_value as value', DB::raw("NULL as item"), DB::raw("NULL as institution_id"), DB::raw("NULL as item_id")])
        ->union($money)
        ->union($personal)
        ->union($investments)
        ->get();

            return view('assets.allassets', ['user_assets' => $union]);

     }
```

Here's my route:

```
Route::get('/dataassets', 'DataassetsController@getUnion');
```

Here's my blade (allassets.blade.php) code:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

<!--  Collapsible accordion rows in bootstrap  -->

<div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h3>All Assets</h3></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
<table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">

    <thead>
        <tr><th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Asset Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    @foreach ($user_assets as $user_asset) <!-- don't forget to add a variable to the loop to index ID's of subrow -->
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo{{$loop->index}}" class="accordion-toggle"> 
       @isset($user_asset->item)
                <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button></td>
        @else
                <td></td>
        @endisset
            <td>{{$user_asset->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$user_asset->type}}</td>
            <td style="text-align:right">${{ number_format($user_asset->value,2)}}</td>
            <?php $var = ($user_asset->name); ?>

        </tr>
        @isset($user_asset->item)


        <tr>
            <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRow"><div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo{{$loop->index}}"> 
            <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                        <th>Institution</th>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>


                        <tr>

                            <td>{{$user_asset->item}}</td>
                            <td> placeholder</td>
                            <td> {{$user_asset->institution_id}}</td>
                            <td> {{$user_asset->item_id}}</td>
                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a></td></tr>


                    </tbody>
            </table>

            </div> </td>
        </tr>
        @endisset
        @endforeach

    </tbody>
</table>
            </div>

          </div> 

      </div>

      <!--     end Bootstrap table    -->
```

Here's a picture of what I get, with one of the children rows popped out:
[Bootstrap table showing only one child at a time with multiple copies of parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnW9Y.png)

Here's a pic of the database tables in question:
[The parent and child tables (other tables referenced above do not have children, only this one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLqGl.jpg)

I'm using Laravel 5.5 & PHP7 on XAMPP
**Any help or suggestions are very welcome.**